# Three.js layer for leaflet

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, leaflet

I am currently trying to build an overlay layer for leaflet. The overlay is supposed to display 3D contents (e.g. buildings). However, I have trouble with keeping the movements on the leaflet map in sync with the ones in the scene in the overlay.

So far the canvas is as large as the map container and it will always overlay the map (like a position: fixed). In order to move around when the user is panning on the map I want to move the camera in the scene (instead of moving all geometries around). For position I use the distance from `lat:0, lng:0` as THREE seems to struggle with fractal positions (e.g. when using decimal gps coordinates). Unfortunately I am struggling to find the correct formula to get the correct positions for the camera (x,y,z).

My attempt so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/hg474d6r/7/ (the `_handleMove` function is the relevant one)

The black dot is the center and for your reference. The red dot should remain static - relative to the map - which it doesn't.

So is there just a small issue in my formula/"calculations" or will this approach not even work at all?

**Update:** updated fiddle with progress and so on

Comment: hi, I'm working on basically the same problem.. did you actually find a solution?

Comment: @jaronimoe no I haven't but switched to mapbox gl instead. It supports e.g. Extrusion out of the box which was sufficient for my use case. Also mapbox allows pitching and tilting out of the box. You could still try to overlay mapbox with a three js layer (then having the same problem as with leaflet of course)

Comment: actually I don't need any 3D features but rather the power of the GPU for large scale data visualization - so for drawing a lot of primitives like points and lines. but I will check out if it also supports these features. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late with a reply here, but just stumbled upon this when I wanted to do something similar and I got your example to work. It seems like it was the distance/height of the camera that was the issue.

Replace the distance calculation on row 139 with this in the example and the red dot will be static:

**var dist = Math.abs((height * 0.5) / Math.tan(fovRad * 0.5));**

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that the Camera will points to a fixed Point. 
If you move the Camera the Direction of the Camera Vector will be changed. 
So You will see this Parallaxe Effekt.